# Add Webapp to iPhone homescreen like TestFlight

Tags: iphone, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

How can I have my webapp be added to the homescreen without having the user press the add to homescreen button.  TestFlight does this when you install it to your phone, I would like to create a similar experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Testflight (and others) do this by letting the user install a specific profile. So the user has to install the profile, which is more complicated, than pressing a "add to homepage button". Also, for the profile way you need to have a server capable of communicating with a specific SSL protocol and the user has to trust you, that the profile does not alter any phone settings, which is the original purpose of such a profile.